# Rails STI: implementing child class edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, sti

There is a lot of discussion around Rails 3 STI and how to use forms, but no definitive answers on StackOverflow. I seem to have run into a similar issue and have attempted the other solutions with no results.

I have two models with the following inheritance set up:

```
User.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name, #more follows


Waiter.rb
class Waiter < User
```

On the form at /waiters/users/[:id]/edit, I am attempting to create a form for editing the waiter. However, I am getting the following error upon loading the edit view:

```
undefined method `waiter_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fbd08cef9d8>:0x007fbd09532fa0>
```

This is my controller found at /app/controllers/admin/waiters/users_controller.rb:

```
  def edit
    form_info
    @user = Waiter.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = Waiter.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully assigned Waiter."
      redirect_to admin_waiters_users_url()
    else
      form_info
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
```

And this is the form located in the edit view:

```
  <%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>
  <%= f.input :email %>

      <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary") do %>
      <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Save
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong here with STI and routing?

UPDATE: here is my rake routes:

```
admin_waiters_users GET    /admin/waiters/users(.:format)                                                            admin/waiters/users#index
                                                                POST   /admin/waiters/users(.:format)                                                            admin/waiters/users#create
                                        new_admin_waiters_user GET    /admin/waiters/users/new(.:format)                                                        admin/waiters/users#new
                                       edit_admin_waiters_user GET    /admin/waiters/users/:id/edit(.:format)                                                   admin/waiters/users#edit
                                            admin_waiters_user GET    /admin/waiters/users/:id(.:format)                                                        admin/waiters/users#show
                                                                PUT    /admin/waiters/users/:id(.:format)                                                        admin/waiters/users#update
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use your routes to see what routes you have defined:

You can run your routes with:

```
rake routes
```

I can not see your routes but perhaps `waiter_path` does not exist.

Perhaps is `user_waiter_path(@user)` or other router.

Please paste your routes for that the people on stackoverflow can help to you.

I can not see the route `waiter_path` on your routes, If you have `waiter_path` inside of your `edit` view you have remove it.

Also, you can specify what controller and action hit,

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, :url => { :controller => "admin/waiters/users", :action => "update"} do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :first_name %>
 <%= f.input :last_name %>
 <%= f.input :email %>
 <%= f.button :submit, "save", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
<% end %>
```

You can check with `f.button` instead `button_tag`

Regards!

Comment: Thanks. Totally forgot to include it.

Comment: That made the form work. But the submit button is not updating the waiter user. Any idea why?

Comment: That should be other question. You must add other question with this topic. I think that you have the problem on `update action`. You must review sent params from form and see on your `update action` what is happening and why the user is not updated. Regards!